# SQL.Посчитать количество записей со статусом SENDING из двух таблиц message и message archive, но вывод должен содержать только 1 запись

Tags: mysql

У меня выходит посчитать только так

```
select COUNT(m.status) "SENDING" from message as m where m.status= 'SENDING'
UNION ALL
select COUNT(msg.status) "SENDING" from message_archive_partition as msg where msg.status= 'SENDING'
```

Но вывод имеет две записи, а нужно одной записью

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете просто сложить вывод двух подзапросов:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(m.status) "SENDING" FROM message m) + 
  (SELECT COUNT(map.status) "SENDING" FROM message_archive_partition map)
as "count";
```

Comment: сумму то не просили вроде. просто два подзапроса, одна строка два столбца

Comment: @teran для этого `+` надо поменять на `,`